# has already been exported. Exported identifiers must be unique.Babel babylon error

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-babylon

I am .net developer i am new in nodejs enviroment
I have a nodeJS project.It was work very well,I addes some feauture and I finished it.Then I deleted that project.Now I must install that project for add new feautures

So I took project code in a folder and then I use

```
npm install
```

and then I use npm build and npm start build commands but it give that error after npm start build command

```
has already been exported. Exported identifiers must be unique.
```

I search for that error.I find that solution.I think Error is about babel/babylon

https://github.com/babel/babylon/releases/tag/v6.11.2

but I did not understand that solution.Should I download
https://github.com/babel/babylon/releases/tag/v6.11.2 that babylon file to under node modules?But in my node modules folder there is no babylon
here is my package.json
How can I install that project to any folder?Just copy files and npm install is enough?

```
{
  "name": "react-seed",
  "version": "0.0.13",
  "description": "Seed project for React apps using ES6 & webpack.",
  "repository": "https://github.com/badsyntax/react-seed",
  "config": {
    "buildDir": "./build",
    "buildDirTests": "./build_tests",
    "devHost": "0.0.0.0",
    "devPort": 8000,
    "remoteHost": "http://yazilimsozluk.com"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "set NODE_ENV=production&& npm run webpack",
    "clean": "rimraf $npm_package_config_buildDir && mkdir $npm_package_config_buildDir",
    "env": "env",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx ./app ./webpack && echo No linting errors.",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "pretest": "npm install && npm run lint",
    "pretest-travis": "npm install && npm run lint",
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=development && node dev-server ./webpack/config",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test karma start --single-run",
    "test-dev": "NODE_ENV=test karma start",
    "test-travis": "NODE_ENV=test karma start --single-run",
    "webpack": "webpack --colors --progress --config ./webpack/config"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.1.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.4",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "intl": "^1.0.0",
    "intl-locales-supported": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.9.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.5",
    "ms-signalr-client": "^2.2.2",
    "normalize.css": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-dnd": "^2.1.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-touch-backend": "^1.5.0",
    "react-dnd-touch-backend": "^0.2.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.8",
    "react-flexgrid": "^0.7.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.0.0-rc-1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.1",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1",
    "superagent": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.0.0-rc-1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.6.1",
    "chai": "^2.3.0",
    "compass-mixins": "^0.12.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^2.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.2.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "glob": "^7.0.3",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "inline-environment-variables-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.12",
    "karma-cli": "0.0.4",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.1.10",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-source-map-support": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.5.1",
    "mocha": "^2.2.4",
    "mocha-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.7",
    "rimraf": "^2.3.3",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "sinon": "^1.14.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "template-html-loader": "0.0.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true,
      "es6": true
    },
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "modules": true,
      "jsx": true
    },
    "globals": {
      "describe": true,
      "it": true,
      "xit": true,
      "xdescribe": true,
      "beforeEach": true,
      "sinon": true
    },
    "plugins": [
      "react"
    ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "rules": {
      "strict": true,
      "indent": [
        2,
        2
      ],
      "quotes": [
        2,
        "single"
      ],
      "new-cap": 0,
      "no-unused-expressions": 0,
      "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
      "react/display-name": 0,
      "react/jsx-quotes": 1,
      "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
      "react/jsx-sort-props": 1,
      "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
      "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
      "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
      "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
      "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
      "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
      "react/prop-types": 1,
      "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
      "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
      "react/wrap-multilines": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Edited

error occur in mockhelper.js in mockPlayer function
here is that file code

```
    import _ from 'lodash';

import * as stoneHelpers from 'utils/stoneTestHelpers';

import { StoneColor,
         SequenceType } from 'constants/AppConstants';

export function mockStone(color = StoneColor.RED, number = 1) {
  return {
    number: number,
    color: color
  };
}

export function mockOkeyStoneWithHelper(okeyStone, helper) {
  return _.extend({}, okeyStone, {
    isOkey: true,
    okeyHelper: helper
  });
}

export function mockStoneWithId(color = StoneColor.RED, number= 1, id) {
  return {
    id: id,
    color: color,
    number: number
  };
}

export function mockPlayer(id, name) {
  return {
    id: id,
    name: name
  };
}

export function mockTable() {
  return {
    players: [
      mockPlayer(1, 'mockPlayer1'),
      mockPlayer(2, 'mockPlayer2'),
      mockPlayer(3, 'mockPlayer3'),
      mockPlayer(4, 'mockPlayer4')
    ],
    scoreboard: []
  };
}

export function mockOpenStoneGroups(owner) {
  return {
    groups: [stoneHelpers.buildStoneGroupSequenceWithStones(
      SequenceType.RAINBOW,
      stoneHelpers.buildStoneRainbow(5, 0),
      owner),
     stoneHelpers.buildStoneGroupSequenceWithStones(
       SequenceType.SAME_COLOR,
       stoneHelpers.buildStoneSameColor(6, StoneColor.GREEN, 300, 4),
       owner)
    ]
  };
}

export function mockOpenStoneGroupsWithGroups(groups) {
  return {
    groups: groups
  };
}

export function mockOpenStoneGroupsForPairs(owner, count) {
  const groups = [];

  while (count-- > 0) {
    groups.push(stoneHelpers.buildStoneGroupPairsWithStones(
      stoneHelpers.buildStonePair(count, StoneColor.RED, count * 100),
      owner
    ));
  }

  return mockOpenStoneGroupsWithGroups(groups);
}

export function mockStartInfo(currentTurn = 0) {
  return {
    stones: _.flatten([
      stoneHelpers.buildStoneSameColor(1, StoneColor.RED, 0, 3),
      stoneHelpers.buildStoneRainbow(13, 300),
      stoneHelpers.buildFreeStoneGroup(400)
    ]),
    discardStones: [
      [stoneHelpers.buildStone(1, StoneColor.RED)],
      [stoneHelpers.buildStone(2, StoneColor.BLACK)],
      [stoneHelpers.buildStone(3, StoneColor.GREEN)],
      [stoneHelpers.buildStone(4, StoneColor.BLUE)]
    ],
    gosterge: stoneHelpers.buildStone(10, StoneColor.BLACK),
    currentTurn: currentTurn
  };
}

export function mockPlayer(id, name, optional) {
  return _.extend({
    id: id,
    name: name
  }, {}, optional);
}

export function mockPlayerFull(id, name) {
  return mockPlayer(id, name, {
    state: {
      turnPoints: 10,
      openPoints: 100,
      openedHands: 0,
      hasOpenedPairs: false
    },
    timeLeft: 10
  });
}

export function mockTable(p1 = mockPlayerFull(1, 'mockPlayer1'),
                          p2 = mockPlayerFull(2, 'mockPlayer2'),
                          p3 = mockPlayerFull(3, 'mockPlayer3'),
                          p4 = mockPlayerFull(4, 'mockPlayer4')) {
  var result = {
    players: [
      p1,
      p2,
      p3,
      p4
    ]
  };
  return result;
}

export function mockMatchStats(ranking, player,
                               score, xp, hands,
                               punish, chips) {
  return {
    player: player,
    stats: {
      ranking: ranking,
      score: score,
      gainedXP: xp,
      openedHands: hands,
      punishment: punish,
      gainedChips: chips
    }
  };
}

export function mockMatchResult(p1 = mockPlayerFull(1, 'mockPlayer'),
                                p2 = mockPlayerFull(2, 'mockPlayer2'),
                                p3 = mockPlayerFull(3, 'mockPlayer3'),
                                p4 = mockPlayerFull(4, 'mockPlayer4')) {
  return {
    rankings: [
      mockMatchStats(1, p1, 100, 50, 2, 1, 400),
      mockMatchStats(2, p2, 50, 25, 1, 1, 200),
      mockMatchStats(3, p3, 25, 10, 1, 0, -100),
      mockMatchStats(4, p4, 10, 10, 1, 3, -200)
    ]
  };
}

export function mockInitialStateGamePlay() {
  return {
    discardStones: [[], [], [], []],
    sequence: [],
    pairs: [],
    selectedStone: null
  };
}
```

Comment: There isn't nearly enough to go on here. What is the actual code that causes the error in the first place? What is the full error, with stacktrace?

Comment: @loganfsmyth thank you for answear.I added code which cause the error at the end of question.I edited question..But I think problem is about npm install.It skip some node modules I think such as babylon .... I upgrade my package.json but it still give error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you posted

> has already been exported. Exported identifiers must be unique.

may not be clear enough if you don't already know what is wrong. To break it down

> Exported identifiers must be unique.

is saying that a file can only export one thing with a certain name. In your specific code you have both

```
export function mockTable(
    p1 = mockPlayerFull(1, 'mockPlayer1'),
    p2 = mockPlayerFull(2, 'mockPlayer2'),
    p3 = mockPlayerFull(3, 'mockPlayer3'),
    p4 = mockPlayerFull(4, 'mockPlayer4')
) {
    // ...
}
```

*and*

```
export function mockTable() {
  return {
    players: [
      mockPlayer(1, 'mockPlayer1'),
      mockPlayer(2, 'mockPlayer2'),
      mockPlayer(3, 'mockPlayer3'),
      mockPlayer(4, 'mockPlayer4')
    ],
    scoreboard: []
  };
}
```

which doesn't make sense. You can't have two functions in the same scope with the same name.

Comment: but it was worked very well.Does babel new versions support 2 functions in the same scope?

Comment: This code was always been wrong, but Babel did not always error on it. Many months ago at this point the error was added, you may just not have updated to the new version until recently. You should just delete one of the functions, since you definitely haven't been using one of them.

Comment: I am using two functions so I can not delete but I will find a solution,thanks

Comment: You have two functions with the same name in the same file, there is no way your code has been using both. The later one overwrites the first one.